# listing the files depends on file creation time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file

At present i am retrieving  the file names depends up on creation time of file ...

```
private void filteringFiles()
{
  string filenamepath = @"C:\defualt\Access\backupdb\";
  List<String> listfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\defualt\Access\backupdb\", "backup-*.zip").ToList();
  List<String> files = new List<String>();
  List<String> getfiles = new List<String>();
  foreach (var allfiles in listfiles)
  {

    files.Add(Path.GetFileName(allfiles));
    //DateTime creationtime = File.GetCreationTime(files);
  }
  if (cbbackupforms.Text == "Month")
  {
    getfiles = (from string s in files where (DateTime.Now.Day - Convert.ToInt32(File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s)).AddDays(-30).Day) < 1) && ((DateTime.Now.Year - (File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s))).Year) == 0) select s).ToList();

  }

  if (cbbackupforms.Text == "ALL")
  {
    getfiles = files.ToList();

  }

  listbox1.DataSource = getfiles;
```

how can i list the file names depends upon creation time in ascending order  ..

I mean if i created file at this time ...that file will be on top of list ... (ascending order depends upon file creation time)

would any one pls help on this...

Many thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
files.OrderBy(f => File.GetCreationTime(f))
```